# Rational homotopy theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, topological-groups, rational-homotopy-theory

I am trying to read the paper "Rational homotopy theory " by Quillen and am stuck with the notion of complete augmented algebra. He had defined the complete augmented algebra and I don't understand the part (b) of the definition, which states that $\operatorname{gr} R$ is generated as an algebra by $\operatorname{gr}_1 R$. Does this $\operatorname{gr}_1 R= \bar{R}/F_2 R$? If so how does it generate $\operatorname{gr} R$?

In addition he also introduced the notion of topology induced by filtration. What is this topology?

Comment: $\operatorname{gr} R $ is (tautologically) a graded algebra, so it makes perfect sense to ask that this algebra be generated in degree $1$. If you don't understand that I am afraid you will have difficulties with Quillen's paper...

Comment: Way to kill the enthusiasm, @abx.

Comment: If I had to make a list of all the maths I learned having difficulties reading famous papers...